# What is wrong with this bar graph?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I try to create a bar graph based on an [example](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/bar-chart/) I found.

I do some modification to origin, but it doesn't work.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[title  = Contributions per category
                          at LaTeX-Community.org,
    xbar,
    y axis line style = { opacity = 0 },
    axis x line       = none,
    tickwidth         = 0pt,
    enlarge y limits  = 0.2,
    enlarge x limits  = 0.02,
    symbolic y coords = {specrand, sphinx3, mcf, gcc, Distributions, Editors},
    nodes near coords,
  ]
  \addplot coordinates { (57727,specrand) (123, sphinx3) (2222,mcf)        (5672,gcc)
                         (2193,Distributions)  (11106,Editors) };
  \legend{Topics, Posts}
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Error log

```
Package pgfplots Error: Sorry, the input coordinate ` sphinx3' h
as not been defined with 'symbolic y coords={specrand, sphinx3, mcf, gcc, Distr
ibutions, Editors}... Maybe it has been misspelled? Or did you mean something l
ike [normalized] sphinx3?.

See the pgfplots package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.20 ...  (2193,Distributions)  (11106,Editors) };
```

What's wrong with LaTeX syntax? Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Spaces. If you look carefully at the error message you see it refers to the symbolic coordinate called ' sphinx3', i.e. with a space first. In the list of `symbolic y coords` leading spaces are stripped, but this does not happen in the coordinate list for `\addplot`. So all you have to do is to change from `(132, sphinx3)` to `(132,sphinx3)`.

You might also want to add `ytick=data` to the `axis` options.

To add a unit after the numbers, redefine `nodes near coords`. The default value is `\pgfmathprintnumber\pgfplotspointmeta`, so if you want a percentage sign after the number, use `nodes near coords ={\pgfmathprintnumber\pgfplotspointmeta\%}`.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[title  = Contributions per category
                          at LaTeX-Community.org,
    xbar,
    y axis line style = { opacity = 0 },
    ytick             = data,
    typeset ticklabels with strut, % improves vertical alignment of some of the ticklabels in this case (compare gcc and mcf with and without)
    axis x line       = none,
    tickwidth         = 0pt,
    enlarge y limits  = 0.2,
    enlarge x limits  = 0.02,
    symbolic y coords = {specrand, sphinx3, mcf, gcc, Distributions, Editors},
    nodes near coords ={\pgfmathprintnumber\pgfplotspointmeta\%},
  ]
  \addplot coordinates { (57727,specrand) (123,sphinx3) (2222,mcf) (5672,gcc)
                         (2193,Distributions)  (11106,Editors) };
  \legend{Topics, Posts}
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. An irrelevant question: how to set unit for data?

Comment: I'd get rid of the darker border around the bars, Tufte-style ;-)

Comment: @KyL Where do you want the unit printed?

Comment: @TorbjørnT.  percentage (%)

Comment: @KyL That's not what I asked, I meant where in the plot do you want to have the unit? And 57000% Do you want the percent of the sum of all the numbers, so there is some calculations involved? Or are you talking about something completely different? If that is the case, then I would suggest making a new question.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. This graph is just an sample for testing LaTeX. Data doesn't matter. I want to show data in graph like `12%`.

Comment: @KyL See updated answer.